# GStreamer splitting MP4 file

Tags: java, gstreamer

I am trying to write a simple pipeline to split an mp4 file on the local storage to multiple chunks with the fixed duration I've been trying to use several different options but none seems to work

btw we have a hard requirement not to use FFmpeg library due to some license concerns so the plugins that I have at the moment are

```
gst-plugins-base-1.8.3
gst-plugins-good-1.8.3

and some bad plugins libs (h264parse, mpegtsmux, hlssink)
```

Could you help me out to solve that problem using GStreamer?

Couple of samples that I've tried

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/tmp/sample/BigBuckBunny_175k.mp4 ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location=/tmp/sample/segments/segment%05d.mp4 max-size-time=10000000000
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/tmp/sample/BigBuckBunny_175k.mp4 ! splitmuxsink location=/tmp/sample/segments/segment%05d.mp4 max-size-time=10000000000
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/tmp/sample/BigBuckBunny_175k.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! splitmuxsink location=/tmp/sample/segments/segment%05d.mp4 max-size-time=10000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result pipeline for splitting MP4 file is shown below (including video/audio streams)

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location={from} ! queue ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! queue ! h264parse ! queue ! mux.video \
demux.audio_0 ! queue ! aacparse !  queue ! mux.audio_0 splitmuxsink location={to} max-size-time={duration} muxer=mp4mux name=mux
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using [`splitmuxsink`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-splitmuxsink.html)

Comment: updated the question with some fresh samples, might be you have the whole sample of the pipeline?

Comment: Not sure what your expectation is - the last sample does re-encoding but works for me. For the visual part at least. For remuxing you should have a qtdemux somewhere.. and connect all the streams you want to present in remuxed streams.

Comment: first of all thanks for your help since i am completely new to the world of gstreamer, actually when i changed the pipeline to `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/hls/SampleVideo_720x480_30mb.mp4 ! qtdemux ! splitmuxsink location=/hls/sample/segment%05d.mp4 max-size-time=10000000000` i was able split the initial mp4 to multiple mp4 files but their duration is different despite im passing max-size-time=10000000000 from 4-12 s interval, is it expected to have different duration here, is there a way to make it constant to 10 s

Comment: It splits at video I-frames. It has to.. or the start of the MP4 would be corrupt video data. If you re-encode there is a `send-keyframe-requests` property if the encoder understands it to make keyframes more matching to the segments. P.S. if you aim for HLS streaming (which is not MP4) there is also a `hlssink` and `hlssink2` elements.

Comment: thank you again, i didn't want to confuse you actually :) hls is just a folder available from the docker. 
might be you can share a sample of what the result pipeline should look like. i'm not sure that i've got this encoding/key-frame feature, just to make sure that we are on the same page. i am expecting that the mp4 file with duration of 180s will be split up to 18 smaller files with duration of 10s each.

Comment: You need to know and understand what an I-frame is in video compression. Then you will understand why there will be a variation in segment lengths if you want segments without video artifacts. It depends on how your video file is encoded..

Comment: hmm i see what you mean, H.264 is the coding that we use, the idea is to decode the video first and after that apply the exact codec again with the fixed duration of i-frame. i'll update on this as soon as i come up with the result pipeline.